# Way to add the text to text box from the list on clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following code which shows a text box.

```
<p>
    <label>Enter the doctor id</label>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="on" name="dr_id" id="user_id" class="user_name" >
</p>
```

Following code is for showing various options from which one can choose one and put it inside text box.The List appears on clicking

> List of doctors

The code is shown below

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

});

</script>

 <a href="#" class="show_hide">List of doctors</a><br />
    <div class="slidingDiv">

        Dr.Prashant Salunke - dr.salunke.<br>Dr.Kalam - dr.apj<br>Dr.Manmohan Singh - dr.economics<br> <a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a>
    </div>


</div><br>
```

I want if to make items in that list clickable, such that if one clicks them they appear at the text box . How do i achieve that ? What changes do i need to make in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a list with ul and li elements like:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>Dr.Prashant Salunke - dr.salunke.</li>
    <li>Dr.Kalam - dr.apj</li>
    <li>Dr.Manmohan Singh - dr.economics</li>
</ul>
```

Then create a click event:

```
$('#list li').click(function()
   {
   $('#user_id').val($(this).text());
   });
```

Comment: Thanks@schnawel007 . May I know if there is also a way to just select part of text from the list item to textbox. For. eg I just want dr.salunke to go in textbox instead of Dr.Prashant Salunke-dr.salunke

Comment: split the text by the "-", but I would give the li element a "data-" attribute like this:
`<ul id="list">
    <li data-name="dr.salunke">Dr.Prashant Salunke - dr.salunke.</li>
    <li data-name="dr.apj">Dr.Kalam - dr.apj</li>
    <li data-name="dr.economics">Dr.Manmohan Singh - dr.economics</li>
</ul>`

And Then display it like this:
`$('#list li').click(function()
   {
   $('#user_id').val($(this).attr('data-name'));
   });`